# How to avoid code repetition using a 3rd party web service - without using dynamic?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I'm using a 3rd party web service where all it's methods have the following signature:

```
SomeResponseClass SomeMethod(SomeRequestClass request)
```

Every method has it's own request class and it's own response class, However there are a few things that all requests have in common, and all responses have in common.

Every request class has a couple of properties for identification: `username` and `token`, and every response class have a couple of properties to indicate if there was an error: `status` and `error`.

I'm looking for an elegant way to create a method that will instantiate my requests - so that I will not have to repeat myself in every method calling the service. Since I can't change the classes, and there is no common interface or base class to all of them, the only solution I found was to use `dynamic`:

```
private T CreateRequest<T>() where T : new()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Token))
    {
        Login();
    }
    // this has to be dynamic for the next 2 rows to pass compilation.
    dynamic request = new T();
    request.username = _UserName;
    request.token = _Token;
    return (T)request;
}
```

And something similar to populate my own entities from the service responses:

```
// response have to be dynamic for getting the error and status properties
private static T CreateServiceResponse<T>(dynamic response) where T : ServiceResponse, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    result.Error = (response == null) ? "Service response is null" : response.error;
    result.Status = (response == null) ? -1 : response.status;
    return result;
}
```

(This method is used inside every method that I use to populate my entities (all derived from `ServiceResponse`) with the data from the service response.)

Is there any way to do something like this without using `dynamic`?
To me, it kinda feels like using a dirty hack...

If I could somehow "inject" a common interface for all requests to implement and a common interface for all responses to implement I could use simple Generics, but I guess that's impossible, or is it?

Comment: Where do the service classes come from? Did you create a service reference?

Comment: Yes, I have a service reference in my project. All the service classes are auto-generated by Visual studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using service references created by visual studio, all generated classes are marked as `partial`. That means you can extend them with your own code. In your case that would be an interface that provides the repetitive properties. You can use that interface as a generic constraint.

You first create the common interface. To make things easy, you use the same name and type for your common properties as defined in the service reference:

```
interface IRequest {
    string username { get; set; }
    string token { get; set; }
}
```

You then create a code file and in the same namespace as the service reference you define a partial class for each service request class (with the same name). Each of these classes implements your interface:

```
partial class SomeRequestClass : IRequest {}
```

Having chosen the same property names and types, you don‘t have to specifically implement the interface.

Finally you use generic constraints:

```
private T CreateRequest<T>() where T : IRequest, new()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Token))
    {
        Login();
    }
    T request = new T();
    request.username = _UserName;
    request.token = _Token;
    return request;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't even though about checking the generated code... However, it does seem to be a lot of coding just to avoid the use of dynamic... Not sure I'm going to do it but that is probably the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I am doing this on a regular basis and usually the coding is done in 5 to 10 minutes even for extensive service references. You just have to name the interfaces, you don‘t need any specific implementation code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess It's just a lot of copy and paste... You know what you convinced me. I'll give it a try and see how much time it will take. Thanks!

Comment: Well, turns out it really is quite fast and easy. Thanks again!